# How to display list item border in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell How to display list item border in sencha touch .The below code i have implement default border is not coming for list

```
 {
            xtype:'list',
            height: '80%',
            store:'SearchStore', 
             itemTpl : '<img src="{country}" width="30" heigh="30"></img><span>{name} </span>',

     }
```

Comment: can you send screenshot how is List  looking for now? I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried code. A few modifications you can do are:

```
{
    xtype: 'list',
    store: 'SearchStore',
    itemTpl: [       // It works perfectly
        '<div>',
        '    <img style="width:30px;height:60px;vertical-align:middle" src="{country}">',
        '    <span style="">{name}</span>', 
        '</div>'
    ].join('')
}
```

Your mistakes: (Though it may not create that problem)

1. `height` was heigh
2. Extra `</img>` tag was there.

Let me know if you face any issue. (And share the screenshot too)